# TortoiseSVN - how to quickly check if UPDATE will result in working copy changes

Tags: tortoisesvn

Is it possible to **quickly** check if clicking **Update** will result in any changes to working copy?

The non-quick way involves going to the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseSVN is *supposed to* have this functionality via Right-click -> TortoiseSVN -> Check for Modifications -> Check Repository https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-cli-main.html#tsvn-cli-checkmods

`svn status -u` (or `--show-updates`) on the command line will definitely get what you need.

Comment: This is incorrect. I checked the log and it showed that my working copy was not the most recent. Then I `checked for modifications` and it showed no files.

Comment: Your WC can be behind the repository head revision without there being changes to any of the items in the section of the repository that your WC was checked out from.

Comment: Behind the **repository** head revision I agree but when I do `Right Click > Show Log`, I can see that the repo has changes and if I were to `Update` my WC, there would be modifications made to my WC but I see nothing in `Show Modifications`.

Comment: Doing `Right Click > Show Log` on my WC folder, it only shows if there are changes to it and subfolders which is what anyone would want. The case you brought up - an increment of the repo rev # but no changes to my folder(+subfolders) of interest - is irrelevant to me as that would indicate that a change was made that is NOT in my folder of interest.

Comment: Ok so it turns out that TortoiseSVN just plain sucks. Turns out that `svn status -u` does exactly what I want **and** it is not equivalent to `Check for Modifications`.

Comment: It's supposed to be the same, per the docs. https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-cli-main.html#tsvn-cli-checkmods

Comment: So honestly, the correct answer is "TortoiseSVN does not have this functionality but to do the same thing do `svn status -u`". Please update your answer with this and I'll accept.

Comment: Oops. Forgot to click on `Check Repository`

Comment: So `Check for Modifications` does exactly what you're looking for when you click on `Check Repository`?